# How to log deleted files with command prompt

Tags: batch-file

So I have a batch file that I run from time to time to delete any file with a .log extension from a specific folder.  However recently I've found the need to log the name of the files that this script deletes (ironically).  So I tried using `del *.log >> "dellog.txt` however it doesn't seem to put anything in the text file.  Am I formatting this wrong or does the del command not output anything?  If so, how would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good answer to this already over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/855901/force-verbose-mode-in-windows-del-command). The DEL command does not give you any output unless you delete an entire directory. What you can do is use a FOR loop and echo each file out and delete them one-by-one:

```
for %A in (*.log) do ( ECHO %A && del /Q "%A" )
```

Comment: So that seems to work from the command prompt but not when I put it in a batch file which is weird.  It just closes the window when I run it from the batch file.  I only have that line and pause in the batch file, am I doing something wrong?  Also i'm running the batch file from the directory where the .log files are.

Comment: In a batch file, you have to double up the percent signs on the variables. :) Use %%A .